# Image filter works on attachement pages but not posts. I can't get the image ID

Tags: images, filters

I'm using a plugin called Exifography. They provide the [capability to use filters](http://www.kristarella.com/2012/07/filtering-exifography-output/) to adjust for your purposes.  In the example provided I'm simply trying to get the height & width of the image and return it.

This works great on the attachment page (image.php) but will not work with posts. I can't figure out how to properly get the image ID in order to query the wp_get_attachment_metadata function.

This will be used on posts with multiple images.

```
function massage_exif($content,$postID,$imgID){
  $imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($imgID);
  $width= $imgmeta['image_meta']['width'];
  $height = $imgmeta['image_meta']['height'];
  array_push($content,$height . 'x' . $width);
return $content;
add_filter('exifography_display_exif','massage_exif');
```

Using ver 4.01 of WP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some discussion with the developer, I was missing some key items in the add_filter line. I needed to pass along the "11","3". The three is the important item here. It is the number of variables to passback... the 3rd being the elusive $imgID.

```
function massage_exif($content,$postID,$imgID){
  $imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($imgID);
  $width= $imgmeta['image_meta']['width'];
  $height = $imgmeta['image_meta']['height'];
  array_push($content,$height . 'x' . $width);
return $content;
add_filter('exifography_display_exif','massage_exif',11,3);
```

Thanks for helping me keep digging until and answer was found.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the image ID, you could try this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: Unfortunately, that is exactly what I can't seem to find.

Comment: In the function parameters, isn't either `$postID` or `$imgID` the attachment ID?

Comment: That is what I would think it would be... but no.  When this filter runs in the image.php template it works.  So, it is getting $imgID there.  However, when run in a normal post, it does not.  I'm completely baffled on this issue. I can't help but think I'm missing something fundamental.